# Solving the Homogeneous equation with constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say $e^{m_1x}$ and $e^{m_2x}$ are the solutions of the differential equation
$$y''+py'+qy=0\tag{1}$$
where $p$ and $q$ are constants.

And the values of $m_1$ and $m_2$ are found by solving the auxiliary equation
$$m^2+mp+q=0\tag{2}$$

We get complex roots if $p^2-4q>0$ and each of the roots $(m_1,m_2)$ can be written in the form $a\pm ib$. So substituting for m in the solutions we get $$e^{m_1x}=e^{ax}(\cos bx +i\sin bx)\tag{3}$$    $$e^{m_2x}=e^{ax}(\cos bx -i\sin bx)\tag{4}$$
Adding $(3)$ and $(4)$ and dividing it by $2$, we get
$$\frac{e^{m_1x}+e^{m_2x}}{2}=e^{ax}\cos bx$$
Also subtracting $(4)$ from $(3)$ and dividing it by $2i$, we get
$$\frac{e^{m_1x}-e^{m_2x}}{2i}=e^{ax}\sin bx$$
Now it is said that $e^{ax}\cos bx$ and $e^{ax}\sin bx$ are the solutions of $(1)$? Substituting these solutions in $(1)$, I get these equations
$$\left[\frac{e^{m_1x}+e^{m_2x}}{2}\right]''+p\left[\frac{e^{m_1x}+e^{m_2x}}{2}\right]'+q\left[\frac{e^{m_1x}+e^{m_2x}}{2}\right]=0$$
$$\left[\frac{e^{m_1x}-e^{m_2x}}{2i}\right]''+p\left[\frac{e^{m_1x}-e^{m_2x}}{2i}\right]'+q\left[\frac{e^{m_1x}-e^{m_2x}}{2i}\right]=0$$
But I don't get to see how these equations equal zero. Also how are $\frac{e^{m_1x}+e^{m_2x}}{2}$ and $\frac{e^{m_1x}-e^{m_2x}}{2i}$ the solutions of $(1)$, when it is given that $e^{m_1x}$ and $e^{m_2x}$ are the solutions of the differential equation

Comment: The solutions of a homogeneous linear ODE form a vector space, so if $e^{m_1x}, e^{m_2x}$ are solutions then any linear combination of them also must be a solution.